# How can I fix these APT repository errors?

Tags: linux, debian, docker, updates, repository

How can I fix these APT repository errors? I'm using Debian GNU/Linux 9.13 (stretch). I'm looking to fix this update error and import the Docker GPG key.

```
root@test:~# apt-get update
Ign:1 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates InRelease
Err:2 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 111.73.1113.145 90]
Get:3 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch InRelease [44.8 kB]
Ign:4 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Err:5 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stretch Release
  404  Not Found
Err:3 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7PB0A8C2F192FFDM
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://security.debian.org stretch/updates Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stretch Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7PB0A8C2F192FFDM

root@test:~# apt-get install tree
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  tree
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 46.1 kB of archives.
After this operation, 106 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 tree amd64 1.7.0-5
  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/t/tree/tree_1.7.0-5_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I have this sources.list:

```
root@test:~# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stretch main

deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main

# deb http://packages.dotdeb.org stretch all
# deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org stretch all
```

As Docker is running on my VM is it safe to import the Docker GPG key?

Answer (score 7):

The problem is because
[Debian 9/stretch moved to archive.debian.org](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-announce/2023/03/msg00006.html).

See the post
[Debian stretch repositories 404 Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76094428/debian-stretch-repositories-404-not-found)
for solutions.

The
[answer by Luis Herrera](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76094521/165358)
recommends these commands :

> replace deb.debian.org with archive.debian.org:
>
> ```
> sudo sed -i s/deb.debian.org/archive.debian.org/g /etc/apt/sources.list
> ```
>
> replace security.debian.org with archive.debian.org/debian-security/:
>
> ```
> sudo sed -i 's|security.debian.org|archive.debian.org|g' /etc/apt/sources.list
> ```
>
> remove line that contains source stretch-updates:
>
> ```
> sudo sed -i '/stretch-updates/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
> ```

You may also do these changes using a text editor.

Comment: ok ,what should be the replacement  from sources.list

Comment: In `/etc/apt/sources.list`, you need to : replace `deb.debian.org` with `archive.debian.org` and replace  `security.debian.org` with `archive.debian.org/debian-security/` and delete the line with `stretch-updates`.

Comment: This finally work for me : deb [trusted=yes] http://archive.debian.org/debian/ stretch main non-free contrib 
deb-src [trusted=yes] http://archive.debian.org/debian/ stretch main non-free contrib 
deb [trusted=yes] http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main non-free contrib

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me(as root):

```
echo "deb [trusted=yes] http://archive.debian.org/debian stretch main non-free contrib" > /etc/apt/sources.list
echo "deb-src [trusted=yes] http://archive.debian.org/debian stretch main non-free contrib" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
echo "deb [trusted=yes] http://archive.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main non-free contrib" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```

You can just copy paste it. It will work even without a text editor installed. Obviously it will overwrite what is in your /etc/apt/sources.list so make sure to save what you had in case you need it.

Now you will be able to:

```
# apt update
# apt install vim
```

Answer (score -2):

It worked this way for me.

Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` to match following:

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian stretch main
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-security  stretch/updates main
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).